# The Tyrian Smith's Name

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, melachim-kings-book-of, book-of-chronicles

[Kings I ch. 7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a07.htm) tells of Solomon enlisting a Tyrian smith named *חירם, Hiram* to fashion many implements that were used in the Temple.

[Chronicles II ch. 2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b02.htm) speaks of the King of Tyre sending a smith named *חורם, Huram*.

Huram is said in [ch. 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b04.htm) to have made basically the same things that Hiram made in Kings. This strongly implies that they were the same person.

**Why do the verses name this man חירם in one place and חורם in the other?**

Comment: Because the letters are sometimes interchangeable?

Comment: You can also ask this question about the many other instances in Tanach where someone's name is written in various ways.

Comment: @Scimonster Support that in an answer and I'll up vote!

Comment: @Fred true, I am wondering if there is any Torah on this particular change, as this person really interests me. If it is too trivial for the site, I understand. I almost didn't post it for that reason.

Comment: David is spelled דָּוִד in Samuel but דָוִיד in Chronicles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Ibn Ezra writes ([Bamidbar 21:22](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01616.html#HtmpReportNum0027_L2))

> אל תבקש דקדוק בשמות
>
> don't expect/ask for grammatical care when it comes to names

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that because the letters are interchangeable they were switched. Which is proper though, I can't tell you.

You could also ask this question on many other cases throughout Tanach. As an example from this week's parsha (Pinchas), Rashi talks about several names that are spelled differently between lists.